# Cannot publish because a project failed to build The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish, code-signing, signtool

I am new to this community and really desperate right now. 
The publishing of my tools wont work.

I have searched the internet already for one week, but couldn't find any solution. Also my colleges haven't encountered my issue before.

This is what I get, if I try to publish my code to our development server.

> Error 7   Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
>
> Error 14  The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(String certThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String path)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  4539    5   EditHotfixDatabaseTool

If I search for the signTool.exe in the windows explorer then it wont show up. So i thought that I would miss it and reinstalled the .Net 4 Framework and the latest SDK for Windows 7 (I am running a Windows 7 (64bit) and using Visual Studio 2010 ).

Nothing helped.
Going manually to the folder of the signTool.exe, I found it.

What would be the issue causing all this if not the singTool?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The certificate must be present on the machine and have the private key. Confirm by clicking "Select from Store..." that the certificate is in the list. If it's not, then export from another working machine with the private key and import the certificate.